# Using a Find*.cmake file with a header only library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am creating a header only library (Library A) that includes another library (Library B) using its `FindB.cmake` file.

I include the FindB.cmake file by having it in a cmake directory and doing:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(B REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(A INTERFACE B::B)
```

The tests on Library A all work fine so B is included successfully in A. To make B available to projects that want to include A, I have in my `AConfig.cmake.in` :

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(B REQUIRED)
```

But when I try to make an application (App C) that uses Library A (with `find_package(A REQUIRED)`), I get an error that cmake cannot find the `FindB.cmake` file. The error goes away if I put the `FindB.cmake` file in the App C project and include it like I did with Library A, but I don't want people using Library A to need the `FindB.cmake` file.

Is there a way to make all of the location information from `FindB.cmake` carry over from Library A to App C without needing to include the actual `FindB.cmake` file?

Comment: Just add script `FindB.cmake` into the installation of the library A (e.g. via `install(FILES)`). Note, that results of that script are specific for the machine where it is run. On that machine the script is known to be worked, so you could run the script again, as a part of `AConfig.cmake`. It is true that on other machine the script could be absent. But that other machine could have Library B installed under **other location**, so result of that script on initial machine cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

@Tsyvarev had the answer.

I added this to install the `FindB.cmake`:

```
install(FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/FindB.cmake"
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/A/cmake
)
```

Then in my `AConfig.cmake.in`, I edited it with the following:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH @CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR@/A/cmake @CMAKE_MODULE_PATH@)

find_dependency(B REQUIRED)
```

I can now add Library A to App C with `find_package(A REQUIRED)` and everything transfers over.

Thanks again @Tsyvarev